# Power window noise when rolling up

Tags: vw, power-windows

I have a 2015 VW Polo and the right rear power window is making a weird noise on the way up. It rolls down normally and the speed at which it rolls up and down is unaffected as far as I can tell. Here's a video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0lt8NEDA1U&feature=youtu.be

All other windows are fine. The car was driven in quite a bit of rain for the last couple of days. The dealer wants to open up the door card and check. I'm wondering if anyone can pinpoint the problematic component and/or suggest an easy DIY fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way forward here is indeed to remove the door card to have a view of the parts that make the window raise and lower.

Something's loose or broken in the window mechanism. The torque required of the electric motor when the window's going up causes whatever-it-is to physically vibrate or move out of alignment, and make that little clanking sound. On the way down, the window mechanism is less stressed (gravity helps!), and the loose or broken piece isn't moved or pressed in the same way, and the sound isn't produced.